# Conditional nd argmin: How can I find the coordinates of the min of a subset of a multidimensional array?

Tags: numpy

I know I can use `argmin` and `unravel_index` to find the index of the smallest value in an ndarray, but what if I want to find the smallest nonzero element, or the smallest element which is not NaN?

Comment: For the NaN case there's simply `numpy.nanargmin`

Comment: @user7138814 Pretty good suggestion there. Added it into the timings test in my post and looks quite efficient!

Comment: @Demetri P Did either of the posted solutions work for you?

Comment: @Divakar Yes, I'll be sure to accept a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach using flattened indices -

```
def flatnonzero_based(a,condition): # condition = a!= or ~np.isnan(a)
    idx = np.flatnonzero(condition)
    return np.unravel_index(idx[np.take(a, idx).argmin()], a.shape)
```

**Benchmarking**

Approaches -

```
def flatnonzero_based(a,condition): # Proposed soln
    idx = np.flatnonzero(condition)
    return np.unravel_index(idx[np.take(a, idx).argmin()], a.shape)

def where_based(a, condition):  # @Paul Panzer's soln
    nz = np.where(condition)
    return np.array(nz)[:, np.argmin(a[nz])]
```

Timings and verification -

```
In [233]: a = np.random.rand(40,50,30)

In [234]: nan_idx = np.random.choice(range(a.size), size = a.size//100, replace=0)

In [235]: a.ravel()[nan_idx] = np.nan

In [236]: condition = ~np.isnan(a)

In [237]: where_based(a, condition)
Out[237]: array([16, 10,  8])

In [238]: flatnonzero_based(a, condition)
Out[238]: (16, 10, 8)

In [239]: %timeit where_based(a, condition)
1000 loops, best of 3: 877 µs per loop

In [240]: %timeit flatnonzero_based(a, condition)
10000 loops, best of 3: 143 µs per loop
```

With `4D` data -

```
In [255]: a = np.random.rand(40,50,30,30)

In [256]: nan_idx = np.random.choice(range(a.size), size = a.size//100, replace=0)

In [257]: a.ravel()[nan_idx] = np.nan

In [258]: condition = ~np.isnan(a)

In [259]: where_based(a, condition)
Out[259]: array([34, 14,  5, 10])

In [260]: flatnonzero_based(a, condition)
Out[260]: (34, 14, 5, 10)

In [261]: %timeit where_based(a, condition)
10 loops, best of 3: 64.9 ms per loop

In [262]: %timeit flatnonzero_based(a, condition)
100 loops, best of 3: 5.32 ms per loop
```

Incorporating [`@user7138814's suggestion`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42333735/conditional-nd-argmin-how-can-i-find-the-coordinates-of-the-min-of-a-subset-of#comment71821178_42333735) -

```
In [267]: np.unravel_index(np.nanargmin(a), a.shape)
Out[267]: (34, 14, 5, 10)

In [268]: %timeit np.unravel_index(np.nanargmin(a), a.shape)
100 loops, best of 3: 4.54 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work (condition is data != 0 or ~np.isnan(data))

```
nz = np.where(condition)
cond_arg_min = np.array(nz)[:, np.argmin(data[nz])]
```